# Laptop shuts down on its own in windows 8.1 but works fine on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, shutdown, dell-inspiron

I am using Dell Inspiron. Its really wierd that my laptop kept shutting down on its own on windows 8.1 but works completely fine on windows 7. This is not a overheating issue as my fan is fine. I clean it ocassionaly with a can of compressed air.

Also, when I booted in windows 7 this was the error I got on my taskbar: There is a problem with your battery so computer might shutdown suddenly.

If that is the case then why Windows 8.1 cant take it and 7 can?

I also Googled about possible reasons so I tried removing the battery for sometime & charging it but laptop shutdown anyway.

Please help.

Comment: Does this happen if the battery is removed?  Did you install the oem  drivers in Windows 7 but not Windows 8 by chance?

Comment: I tried removing the battery & kept the charge on but it got shutdown anyway. Whats oem drivers? how do I check that?

Comment: OEMs normally provide software to manage your battery. What do you mean it "kept the charge on" the battery is not even installed it shouldn't have even been charging.

Comment: I meant I plugged in the charger anyway

Comment: Do you use a minimum resolution of atleast 1024x768? below which is not compatible with win8.1

Comment: @Ramhound how do I know and where do I check for OEM drivers?

Comment: Yes I do but how is it connected